# Connecting to Event Hub

Tags: websocket, azure-eventhub

In my code below I am attempting to create a producer client that i can use to send events to a Event Hub. I am getting a ***System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'The WebSocket protocol is not supported on this platform.*** error Any guidance on how i can resolve this would be much appreciated. FYI my platform is Windows 7, although this program is intended to run on a windows 2008 server or later.

```
    var producerOptions = new EventHubProducerClientOptions
                 {
                     ConnectionOptions = new EventHubConnectionOptions
                     {
                         TransportType = EventHubsTransportType.AmqpWebSockets,

                     },

                     RetryOptions = new EventHubsRetryOptions
                     {
                         MaximumRetries = 5,
                         TryTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
                     }
                 };

                 var producer = new EventHubProducerClient(connectionString, eventHubName, producerOptions);
```

***//here is where the error occurs. which is inside a try - catch block***

```
var eventBatch = await producer.CreateBatchAsync();
```

......

Comment: change transport type if you want to use same code in win7 machine

Answer (score 1):

The Event Hubs client library relies on the underlying framework for its transport communication.  In this case, it sounds as if you're using the full .NET Framework on Windows 7, where web sockets is not supported.

So long as your aren't using a UWP application, changing the target framework to .NET Core and using the `netstandard2.0` target from the client library may work.  *(see: [this PR](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/26429))*

More detail can be found in the accepted answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48011763/windows-7-websocket-platformnotsupportedexception), which also contains some advice for third party packages that may work as a polyfill.